# Converting ISBN number of a Book to HexaDecimal for Writing To RFID tags

Tags: java, rfid, hex, isbn

I am in the process of Writing ISBN values to UHF RFID cards , So that I need to scan the barcode of the book and to receive the ISBN and then I need to convert that ISBN of(13 digit integer) to hexadecimal value to write to the UHF RFID tags.

As of now I can able to Scan the barcode and receive the ISBN number, but I need some help on converting ISBN to hexadecimal value for writing to the UHF RFID tags in Java.

Comment: Are you sure this is necessary? Seems like a strange requirement.

Comment: Yes , it is strongly needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
   BigInteger toHex=new BigInteger(dec,10);// use this to convert your number to big integer so that any number can be stored where dec is your input number in base 10 in string
     String s=toHex.toString(16);//convert your number into hexa string which can be directly stored in rfid tag
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Long.valueOf(isbnString, 16)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28long%29) . Create a method toHex and if input string contains `"-"` then replace them with empty String , after that create and return the number. Please note that `Long.valueOf` can throw `NumberFormatException` E.g.

```
public static Long toHex(String isbn) {
    String temp = isbn;
    if (isbn.length() > 10) {
        temp = isbn.replaceAll("-", "");
    }

    return Long.valueOf(temp, 16);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long isbn1 = 9780071809L;
        Long isbn2 = 9780071809252L;

        System.out.println(toHex(isbn1.toString()));
        System.out.println(toHex(isbn2.toString()));
        System.out.println(toHex("978-0071809252"));
    }
```

Comment: That is no way to 'handle' `NumberFormatException`. As it's already a `RuntimeException`, you should let the original exception propagate.

Comment: @user1099280 If you supply a string that cannot be converted into number e.g. "II" then the method `toHex` will throw `NumberFormatException`. You can handle it as you will like